# How to overwrite module-ui/Component/Form/Element/DataType/Date.php::public?

Tags: magento2, overrides

I changed the prepare function in vendor/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/DataType/Date.php. Now I want to override it in a way that is update safe. How would I do that? Using my own module?

**Magento 2.1.12**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty update save if a function isn't marked as deprecated.

If it's public try to use a plugin to achieve your goal.

Still each modifications needs to be reviewed when upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

**This resolve the problem in grid date format**

Create file in app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

paste this:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Purchase Date</item>
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm:ss </item> <!-- CHANGE HERE your date format -->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```
````